# Where should unit tests live in an angularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to stick to the pure angular recommendations for unit testing:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

But it really doesn't tell me where they should live. My guess would be inside an angular service, probably segregated by page or in the same file as the base controller, sort of a base testing factory or service.

Comment: Your put link about AngularJS (1.x). But question tagged as Angular 2+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the CLI to create your app and new objects, it will automatically create all of the tests as separate files with the .spec.ts extension.
So if the CLI does it that way, that is probably the recommended way.

Comment: Interesting. So your saying unit testing should live outside the main application which we are writing via an IDE not the CLI. We may give this a shot; we need to do a lot of canvas and 3D responsiveness testing. Are there other approaches or is this pretty much it? Sorry, just learning this stuff.

Comment: Use the CLI (angular 2+) to create a fake quick app in seconds. You will see how they set up the test files. The generated README.md will tell you how to run the tests. But... I answered before you removed the Angular tag, so I am not sure if all would apply to the old version of AngularJS. https://cli.angular.io/